# Mongodb whats faster $in or $or?

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

Which query will be faster?
Len of ObjectId list can be more than 2.

```
db.house.find(
    { persons:
        { $elemMatch:
            { person_id:
                { $in:
                    [ ObjectId("570028671d41c8eaeb6c9ce8"), 
                      ObjectId("570028681d41c8eaeb6c9e38")
                    ]
                 }
             }
         }
     })

db.house.find(
    { $or:
        [{ persons:
            {$elemMatch:  
                {person_id:ObjectId("570028671d41c8eaeb6c9ce8")}}
         }, 
         {persons:{$elemMatch:              
                {person_id:ObjectId("570028681d41c8eaeb6c9e38")}}
         }]
    })
```

I have indexes for: persons, persons.person_id. I making queries from Django (mongoengine) if it does matter. There is about 100k houses and 2k persons in my db for now.
House documents are like that:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570031aa1d41c8ed54393b19"),
    "persons" : [
        {
            "person_id" : ObjectId("570028671d41c8eaeb6c9dff"),
            "t" : "150 t"
        },
        {
            "person_id" : ObjectId("5700312d1d41c8ed54393b05"),
            "t" : "1 g"
        },
        {
            "person_id" : ObjectId("5700312d1d41c8ed54393b06"),
            "t" : "70 y"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document? Furthermore, you can always use `var start = new Date().getTime(); doYouStuff; print(new Date().getTime() - start)` to measure the difference or use **[`.explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)**

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg added sample to post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in), `$in` should be used instead of `$or` whenever possible.

But you also don't need to use `$elemMatch` as you're directly matching against a single field, so you can simplify your query to:

```
db.house.find(
    { 'persons.person_id':
        { $in:
            [ ObjectId("570028671d41c8eaeb6c9ce8"), 
              ObjectId("570028681d41c8eaeb6c9e38")
            ]
        }
    })
```